# class weighted classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance

I am working on my multi-class classification project and I have a question:

I have three classes in proportion: 50%, 47% and 3%. I decided to use `class_weight="balanced"` parameter in random forest classifier. Now I want to calculate accuracy. Should I use balanced accuracy or can I use common accuracy?

Answer (score 3):

Accuracy is by definition "weighted" according to the classes proportions: it counts the number of correct instances in the full dataset, so a class with N% of the instances represents N% of the accuracy score. In other words, the 50% class accounts for 50% of the score, but the 3% class represents only 3%.

This is why in general [accuracy should not be used to measure performance with a imbalanced dataset](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/110124/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-accuracy/). [This question about taking imbalance into account in the performance](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/85981/64377) might also be of interest.